# Check input if it is even or both a number

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function with given two numbers, 'isEitherEvenOrAreBoth7' returns whether at least one of them is even, or, both of them are 7.

So far here's my code:

```
function isEitherEvenOrAreBoth7(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 || num2  % 2 === 0) || (num1 && num2 === 7) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var output = isEitherEvenOrAreBoth7(3, 7);
console.log(output); // --> MUST RETURN false

var output = isEitherEvenOrAreBoth7(2, 3);
console.log(output); // --> MUST RETRUN true
```

For some reason both of my output returns 'true' which is not right.
Can you see my mistakes?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you need to check each individually. But as another way of explaining it... You can't do "If `a` or `b` are even", because JavaScript thinks that's "If `a`... **or** `b` is even". The first part, "If `a`" will return true as long as `a` isn't 0. You have to do: "If `a` is even or `b` is even".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isEitherEvenOrAreBoth7(num1, num2) {
    return (num1 % 2 === 0 || num2 % 2 === 0) || (num1 === 7 && num2 === 7)
}
```

You need to perform the logic checks on both numbers individually, rather than `num1 || num2 is even`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(num1 || num2  % 2 === 0) || (num1 && num2 === 7)
```

This does not do what you think it does. <sub>I'm assuming the missing parens are a mistake in writing the question.</sub>

`num1 || num2 % 2 === 0` is equivalent to `num1 == true || num2 % 2 === 0`

the same principle applies to

`num1 && num2 === 7` which could be written as `num1 == true && num2 === 7`

With that original check, as long as num1 isn't 0, the function returns true.

Answer (score -1):

You can write it in a simple way

```
function isEitherEvenOrAreBoth7(num1, num2){
    if(!num1){
        return false;
    }
    if(!num2){
        return false;
    }

    if(num1 == 7 && num2 == 7){
        return true;
    }
    if(num1 % 2 === 0 && num2 % 2 === 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```